# how can i get current time with milliseconds while creating table in hive

Tags: mysql, unix, hive, unix-timestamp

I am trying to create a table in hive. The table should have a column with insertion time in millisecond precession.

I tried using from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')  .

I think `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns time in seconds only. Because of this the milliseconds part is always '000'. This column in my table has only following values '2016-03-01 22:14:07.000', '2016-03-01 22:14:08.000'.

Please help me to get timestamp with milliseconds in it.

Comment: Edited for better readability.

Comment: Thankyou Alexei. I think Hive UDF is the only option to solve this..

Comment: I believe this is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737561/how-do-i-get-millisecond-precision-in-hive