# Hive: how to convert millisecond timestamps?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sparklyr

I am trying to use the `HIVE UDFs` (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) 
from `Sparklyr` to read-in properly some timestamps.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to parse correctly the following timestamp:

```
unix_timestamp('2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z', 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS' )
```

returns `NA`s..

Any ideas? What is the right pattern here?
THanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote `T` and `Z`

```
hive> select unix_timestamp('2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" );
OK
1298959204
```

Or try this if you are not afraid to be clumsy:

```
select unix_timestamp(cast(regexp_replace('2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z', '(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})T(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}).(\\d{3})Z', '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6.$7' ) as timestamp))
```

To convert from `EST` to `UTC`, use the following:

```
hive> select to_utc_timestamp(unix_timestamp('2011-03-01T00:00:04.226Z', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" )*1000, 'EST');
OK
2011-03-01 05:00:04
```

Multiplication with `1000` is required because, from [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF):

> Fractional values are considered as seconds. Integer values are considered as milliseconds.. E.g to_utc_timestamp(2592000.0,'PST'), to_utc_timestamp(2592000000,'PST') and to_utc_timestamp(timestamp '1970-01-30 16:00:00','PST') all return the timestamp 1970-01-31 00:00:00

Comment: that returns a bigint type. Do you know why I cant use `to_utc_timestamp(mytime, 'EST')` where mytime is the `unix_timestamp` that we just created? how would you convert that to a timestamp type?

Comment: assuming the orginal timestamp is in `EST` and I want it in `GMT`

Comment: thanks! last quick question: why Am I losing the millisecond part in the timestamp?

Comment: actually I get `1298955604` when I use `unix_timestamp`. Why is that?

Comment: @Noobie I think because that's how the `unix_timestamp` function works.

Comment: No I mean my `bigint` is different than yours! :)

Comment: Not quite sure how that is happening. You're losing milliseconds and I'm not? That's strange. :D

Comment: nice ! can you just explain what the `regex` syntax is doing? I dont get the `$` thing

Comment: Whatever is between parantheses will be treated as one group so `(\\d{4})` at the start is group 1 which I am accessing using `$1`. So on and so forth.

Comment: Also, the difference you were getting while using `unix_timestamp` was most probably due to the difference in our timezones.

Comment: Please note that you are loosing the milliseconds (I wrote this part in the manual :-))

Comment: cast as timestamp and again cast as double and substract. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737561/how-do-i-get-millisecond-precision-in-hive

Comment: unix_timestamp(<your_column>, <time_format>) * 1000

to milliseconds

refs: https://currentmillis.com/  
Hive* unix_timestamp() * 1000