# TimeDiff Calculation needed Including Milliseconds in HIVE

Tags: hive

We need to calculate the TIME DIFF along with Milliseconds in HIVE Using HUE.

Please find the below screen shot.

```
select 
((unix_timestamp('2017-12-26 14:35:19.609') 
- unix_timestamp('2017-12-26 14:35:18.779'))*1000) as timediff
```

Output :

```
timediff
 1000
```

In the above case we are getting only Seconds but we are not able to get the Milliseconds Precision.

Could you please provide the solution to achieve this issue using HIVE.(Without Using UDF's in HIVE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring from this answer,for milliseconds, you shouldn't  use the `unix_timestamp` functions because these consider date as seconds since epoch.

[How do I get millisecond precision in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737561/how-do-i-get-millisecond-precision-in-hive)

So, you could `CAST` it to `TIMESTAMP` and then `DOUBLE` to get the desired result.

```
SELECT ROUND((CAST(CAST('2017-12-26 14:35:19.609' AS TIMESTAMP) AS DOUBLE) 
            - CAST(CAST('2017-12-26 14:35:18.779' AS TIMESTAMP) AS DOUBLE)) * 1000)
as timediff

timediff 
---------
 830
```